# Foreach loop in jade (node.js template engine)

Tags: node.js, foreach, associative-array, pug

Ok, I am getting an associative array from node server and trying to render it in Jade. I obviously need a foreach loop, but nothing seems to work! I tried these both codes:

```
- foreach row in rows {
    li= row
- }
```

and

```
- rows.forEach(function(item)) {
    li= item
- })
```

the array I am passing is called "rows". Any idea why this is not working? I am getting this error:

```
500 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and, with the second code:

```
500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try

```
each item in rows
    li= item
```

Answer (score 6):

Your second example would work except you have a small syntax error in it - an extra parentheses, it should be:

```
- rows.forEach(function(item) {
  li= item
- })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
ul
  each val, index in ['zero', 'one', 'two']
    li= index + ': ' + val
```

or

```
ul
  each val, index in {1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
    li= index + ': ' + val
```

see this [link](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#for)