# jade inside jade variable

Tags: node.js, pug

I am slowly learning nodejs, express, and jade. Here is what I am trying to accomplish essentially:

```
  ul.nav

- var obj = { 'home':'i.icon-home.icon-white Home', 'about':'About' }
  - each val, key in obj
    - if (id == key)
      li.active
        a(href='#{key}') #{val}
    - else
      li
        a(href='#{key}') #{val}
```

Basically, I am trying to print a nav list but for the "Home" li I want to be able to show a little icon before it. But instead of compiling the jade in the variable to HTML it prints it out plain text (along with if I wrap it with the html I am trying to use. These conditions are essential to my program so any help would be very beneficial, thank you very much!!!

Comment: See this Answer on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366402/foreach-loop-in-jade-node-js-template-engine/37792678#37792678)

Answer (score 5):

If your line starts with a `-` you writing JavaScript.
Otherwise it's jade.
Jade has its own condition and flow control constructs and keywords (`each`, `if` and `else`), so don't prefix them with a `-`

```
ul.nav
each val, key in obj
  if id == key
    li.active
      a(href='#{key}') #{val}
  else
    li
      a(href='#{key}') #{val}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would switch up your jade a bit.

use a for on the obj like this:

```
-  for(var key in obj){
    a(href='#'+key)= obj[key]
-  }
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/w3eCpZmw Doing that I get the error at the bottom of that paste, any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "if(id == key)" condition? where is id coming from. It looks to be like id is undefined. Also, is there any particular reason you are using an associative array here?

Comment: Well, I am trying to accomplish a dynamic nav bar with bootstrap. If id = "home" then the Home nav button is "active."

Comment: Any idea how to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

inside 'href' type '#'+key

```
ul.nav
- var obj = { 'home':'i.icon-home.icon-white Home', 'about':'About'}     
each val, key in obj
  if id == key
    li.active
      a(href='#'+key) #{val}
  else
    li
      a(href='#'+key) #{val}
```