# node.js unexpected token ; canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

here is my code, I cannot work out why the browser is telling me that  }); is an unexpected token in my code..

```
script
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

  var c =  canvas.getContext('2d');

  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;

  var controller = new Leap.Controller();

  controller.on( 'frame' , function(frame){
    c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    var numberOfFingers = frame.fingers.length;
    c.font = "200px Arial";
    c.textAlign = 'center';
    c.textBaseline = 'middle';
    c.fillText( numberOfFingers , width/2 , height/2 );
  });
  controller.connect();
```

and here is the syntax error that chrome is throwing up, its probably very simple but I can't see whats wrong!

```
 SyntaxError: /Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/views/hand.jade:33
      31|       c.textBaseline = 'middle';
      32|       c.fillText( numberOfFingers , width/2 , height/2 );
    > 33|     });
      34|     controller.connect();
      35| 



Unexpected token ;
      at Function (<anonymous>)
      at assertExpression (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-      therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:31:3)
    at Object.Lexer.attrs (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:648:20)
    at Object.Lexer.next (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:868:15)
    at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:114:46)
    at Parser.lookahead (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:100:23)
    at Parser.peek (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:77:17)
    at Parser.tag (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:733:22)
    at Parser.parseTag (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:719:17)
    at Parser.parseExpr (/Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:188:21)
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me, I don't see a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jade is trying to interpret your nesting, I would avoid using jade to compile JavaScript blocks. [This person had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366402/foreach-loop-in-jade-node-js-template-engine)

have a look at serving [static content](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content) with nodejs

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js');
```

Comment: Hi, I put the code into a js file and then included it in the jade script(src='/js/hand.js'). It works fine now and it is a much cleaner way of doing things! thanks for your help. I'm new to node.js!

Comment: thanks for accepting, have fun with node and the motion controller!